# Coordinates field Twitter Streaming api

Tags: python, json, tweepy, twitter-streaming-api

I am trying to use Twitter streaming api to collect filtered tweets with some coordinates so that I can map them. Last night when I was collecting tweets ,there was a coordinates field in the Json object returned by streaming api , Today i am trying to do the same thing just to filter tweets further that only those tweets be selected where coordinates is not null. But every Json object i am getting does not have a coordinates field. I have searched google and Twitter Api documentation but to no avail. What is the issue and how can i approach this?

Code:

```
if (json_object["user"]["geo_enabled"]==True):
    print json_object["user"]["coordinates"]  #This doesn't print anything
```

Answer (score 1):

The `coordinates` field is not populated by default because of privacy reasons. The user has to specifically turn on this geolocation feature in their profile. The reason why you are not seeing it used is because very few people enable it -- fewer than 1% of tweets. The `place` field is more often used. However, it will not give you a point location. It has a place name and a bounding box.

Answer (score 0):

to retrieve coordinate or place (if coordinates are None), of all tweets with word love, I use:

```
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q='love', count = 10).items():
    if (tweet.coordinates is not None):
        lon = tweet.coordinates['coordinates'][0]
        lat = tweet.coordinates['coordinates'][1]
     elif (tweet.place  is not None):
         # counding box of location
         bbox = tweet.place.bounding_box.coordinates
         lon = bbox[0][0][0]
         lat = bbox[0][0][1]
```